# Phoenix: changeset does not take into account changes on foreign keys

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I am trying to update values for a record in the console `ies -S mix` .

```
iex> video = Repo.one(from v in Video, limit: 1)
%Rumbl.Video{...}
```

if I change the title of the video, everything seems to be working correctly.

```
iex> changeset = Video.changeset(video, %{title: "some title"})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{title: "some title"}, 
errors: [], data: #Rumbl.Video<>, valid?: true>
```

But changing a foreign key seems to have no effect:

```
iex> changeset = Video.changeset(video, %{category_id: 3})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{},
errors: [], data: #Rumbl.Video<>, valid?: true>
```

What should I do to for the changes on the foreign key to be taken into accoung ?

Here is the model

```
defmodule Rumbl.Video do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model

  schema "videos" do
    field :url, :string
    field :title, :string
    field :description, :string
    belongs_to :user, Rumbl.User, foreign_key: :user_id
    belongs_to :category, Rumbl.Category, foreign_key: :category_id

    timestamps()
  end

  @required_fields ~w(url title description)
  @optional_fields ~w(category_id)

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_required([:url, :title, :description])
    |> assoc_constraint(:category)
  end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ecto 2.2, [the fourth argument to `cast` is opts](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4), not optional fields. It used to be optional fields earlier which was deprecated in v2.1 with a recommendation to use `validate_required` instead. This was [apparently removed in v2.2.0](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/6e4f1fc72e3b385ab281ff88acae7e4c02f7d7d5) although I can't find it in the changelog. You should change your code to this for Ecto 2.2:

```
struct
|> cast(params, @required_fields ++ @optional_fields)
|> validate_required([:url, :title, :description])
```

or do this:

```
@required_fields ~w(url title description)a
@optional_fields ~w(category_id)a
```

and

```
|> cast(params, @required_fields ++ @optional_fields)
|> validate_required(@required_fields)
```